# Data manipulation using a script

Tags: unix

I have data in the following format :

```
Key1:Value1 Key2:Value2 Key3:Value3  
A  
B   
C   
D  
Key1:Value4 Key2:Value5 Key3:Value6  
A1  
B1  
C1   
Key1..
```

and so on. The number of keys is always three, and in this same order. No extra lines between the values A,B,C,D in the original data set.

I want to get output in the format

```
Value3, A B C D   
Value6, A1 B1 C1   
.  
.  
.
```

Any thoughts on a script I might be able to use to get this done

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can help you but depends on what type of values those are in general you can write it up to match for Key3: [Pattern to match value] and graph that and then all successive lines before the next Key1 can be grabbed manually with a for loop and stop until you get to new key line and repeat for each section.

Pseudocode:

```
current_key = ""
while !EOF:
    line = next_line()
    if line has regular expression for "Key3: Value":
        process for Value
        current_key = Value
    else 
        process line as a regular ABCD value and print or whatever
```

There isn't much error checking but hopefully that helps get you going.